# A value of type 'CroppedFile?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File?'

Tags: flutter

Since this morning i have a problème with this function

```
 Future<void> cropImage(pickedImage) async{
    File? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
        sourcePath: pickedImage!.path,
        aspectRatioPresets: [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
        ],
        androidUiSettings: const AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
            toolbarColor: Colors.red,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            lockAspectRatio: false),
        iosUiSettings: const IOSUiSettings(
          minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
        )
    );
    final File imageFile = File(croppedFile!.path);
    await uploadToStorage(imageFile);

  }
```

From instruction "await ImageCropper().cropImage(" to it's closure is underlined in red, when i hover on it i get this
" A value of type 'CroppedFile?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File?'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'File?'. "

i tried upgrading the dependenscies no succes,
a also tried to change this ligne

```
final File imageFile = File(croppedFile!.path);
```

to

```
final File imageFile = croppedFile != null ? File(croppedFile.path) : null;
```

no succes please for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is because the package **image_cropper** introduced a breaking change in version 2.0.0 which changed the result of **ImageCropper().cropImage** from **File**
to **CroppedFile**.

So your code should be updated to:

```
Future<void> cropImage(pickedImage) async {
  CroppedFile? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
    sourcePath: pickedImage!.path,
    aspectRatioPresets: [
      CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
    ],
    uiSettings: [
      AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
          toolbarColor: Colors.red,
          toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          lockAspectRatio: false),
      IOSUiSettings(
        title: 'Cropper',
      )
    ],
  );
  final File imageFile = File(croppedFile!.path);
  await uploadToStorage(imageFile);
}
```

Comment: thanks but now i have 2 problèmes, 1. "The named parameter 'androidUiSettings' isn't defined."
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'androidUiSettings'. and 2. "The named parameter 'iosUiSettings' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'iosUiSettings'.dartundefined_named_parameter ", i tried removing the "const" but still same problem

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention, those two were also replaced by a shared "uiSettings" param in a newer version. I updated my answer.

Comment: No more error, thanks,